# $set and $pull in MongoDb over Same Document

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

i have a product profile, and when i want to edit the product, i would like that the user can, Edit fields in the producto (title, price....), upload a new image, and delete some image. All of this at the same time, in the same operation.

I have this code, that works but not at all.

```
const producto = await Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id, 
      {
      '$pull': {"images":  {"filename": imagesDelete }}, 
      '$set': {title, categoria, subCategoria, price, description, contacto}},     
      {new: true}
    );
```

with this code i can: upload an image and edit form, upload an image and delete some image. But when i want to upload image, delete image, and edit form. Not works....
Someone can tell why?

Here is the complete code in the editProduct:

```
exports.editarProductoUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  //REVISAR SI HAY ERRORES
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  console.log(req.body);
  const { imagesDelete, title, categoria, subCategoria, price, description, contacto } = req.body;

  try {
    //   //REVISAR EL ID
    const productoTest = await Producto.findById(req.params.id);

    //   //SI EL PRODUCTO EXISTE O NO!!!
    if (!productoTest) {
      console.log("hay un error en edicion");
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Producto no encontrado" });
    }

    // //   //Verificar el PRODUCTO
    if (productoTest.author.toString() !== req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No Autorizado para Editar" });
    }

    if (imagesDelete !== undefined) {
      if (typeof imagesDelete === "string") {
        cloudinary.uploader.destroy(imagesDelete, function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).json({
              ok: false,
              menssage: "Error deleting file",
              errors: err,
            });
          }
          console.log(res);
        });
      } else {
        for (let filename of imagesDelete) {
          console.log(filename);
          cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                menssage: "Error deleting file",
                errors: err,
              });
            }
            console.log(res);
          });
        }
      }
    }

    //ACTUALIZAR PRODUCTO
    const producto = await Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id, 
      {
      '$pull': {"images":  {"filename": imagesDelete }}, 
      '$set': {title, categoria, subCategoria, price, description, contacto}},     
      {new: true}
    );

    
    const images = req.files.map((f) => ({
      url: f.path,
      filename: f.filename,
    }));

    //if(producto.images === undefined) return null;
    producto.images.push(...images);
    console.log(producto.images);

    await producto.save();
    res.json({ producto });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Hubo un Error");
  }
};
```

Here a snapshot of the form, to see the fields:

[image: Edit Form Product]

Answer (score 0):

`$pull` and `$set`

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "123"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    images: {
      filename: "123"
    }
  },
  "$set": {
    title: "banana",
    categoria: "b",
    price: 200
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HSiFxqEM62_)

nodejs mongoose

```
let query = {
  _id: "123"
};
let update = {
  "$pull": {
    "images": {
      "filename": "123"
    }
  },
  "$set": {
    "title": "banana",
    "categoria": "b",
    "price": 200
  }
};

Producto.updateOne(
  query, 
  update, 
  function(err, result) {     
    if (err) {
      ...   
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, in this case, how do you identify the document that you want update? do not i need to pass the product id? then is not necessary use {new: true}? If i use this query {} i will update all the documents in the collection...isn't it? In nodeJs. This method is not supported!!!

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Thanks for your update, still not works, not edit my form, and not push my new images. thanks for your time

Comment: I tryed again, and not works. I don't understand why: const producto = await Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id, 
      {
      '$pull': {"images":  {"filename": imagesDelete }}, 
      '$set': {title, categoria, subCategoria, price, description, contacto}},     
      {new: true}
    );  doesn't works at the same time.